# Get Attachments with useQuery

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I'm trying to get files from a working endpoint. I got some files using fetch on the component directly, but I want to use my useGetDocumentQuery to get the document from the endpoint. I'm getting to the end point fine by passing the correct parameters but when debugging I get an error: Parse ERROR.

**This is my processApiSlice.js:**

```
import { apiSlice } from "../../api/apiSlice";

export const processApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ["Documents"],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        
        getDocument: builder.query({
            query: (query) => (
                {
                    url: `/GetDocument?containerName=${query.containerName}&blobName=${query.blobName}`,
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                    },
                    responseType: 'blob',
                }),
            }),       
    })
});

export const {
    useGetDocumentQuery,
} = processApiSlice;
```

**This is my component:**

```
export const DocumentationCard = ({id,expanded,setExpanded}) => {
  const [documentQuery, setDocumentQuery] = useState(null);

  const {
    data: getDocumentQuery,
    refetch: getDocumentRefetch,
    isLoading: isGetDocumentLoading,
    isFetching: isGetDocumentFetching,
    isSuccess: isGetDocumentSuccess,
    isError: isGetDocumentError,
    error: getDocumentError,
  } = useGetDocumentQuery(documentQuery);

const handleDownloadDocument = (document) => {
    const newDocumentQuery = {
      containerName: selectedProcess?.ContainerName,
      blobName: document.Name,
    }
    setDocumentQuery(newDocumentQuery);
    handleDownloadClick()
  }

const handleDownloadClick = async() => {
      const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(getDocumentQuery);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = downloadUrl;
      link.download = `${documentQuery.blobName}`;
      link.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); 
  }
```

Get the Files using the useMutationQuery, but it fails.